# Backend Server fetching data vs UI fetching data

Tags: web, architecture

I have an architecture question.

I am currently working on a system architecture for an Employee information system which will show all the employee information. But the information what needs to be shown to user is currently stored in two systems. But on UI for user we need to show the data in consolidated view. We have two option to approach this.

Option#1:

One backend server which fetches both the data from the two systems and then send it UI to display.

Option#2:

One backend server sends the data from one system and links to get the data from other system.UI then fetches the data from other system to display it on UI.

According to me the Option#2 is better since the data is fetched by UI as and when needed. But the concern with this approach is UI needs to make repeated calls to system2 which makes lot of HTTP requests.

Can I get suggestions on which option is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can put both the calls in parallel instead of sending the links from first service..

Comment: Please provide more information to support your answer. And here the OP is asking for suggestions with a proper reason and logic `Can I get suggestions on which option is better and why?`. You could have used comments if you just wanted to say this.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use one Back-end server as a point of contact for UI. It fetches data from both services.**

Pros:

- One Back-end server can cache the data for multiple users
- Less potential race conditions in UI
- One Back-end service to validate requests and secure connection
- In case data sets have some relations, system can implement [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/)
- Packed big data can be faster transferred than two separate requests

Cons:

- If one service is down, users won't see any information till Back-end times out on the request and send the partial response
- In general if those two sets are big, it takes longer for a UI to show something valuable to an user
- Another server/service to maintain

**2. Use two Back-end services and merge data sets from both in UI.**

Pros:

- Valuable feedback quicker visible in UI, when for instance one service is down
- Two transportation layers (HTTP for the first one and WebSockets for the other one)

Cons:

- Opposite statement to Pros from Option 1 :)